# How to loop through a range of decimal numbers in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, seq

I'd like to generate a sequence of equally spaced decimal numbers.

For example, I want to `echo` all numbers between `3.0` and `4.5`, with step `0.1`. I tried `$ for i {3.0..4.5..0.1}; do echo $i; done`, but this gives an error.

I also tried `$ for i in $(seq 3.0 4.5 0.1); do echo $i; done` but nothing happens.

Comment: Bash doesn't do floating point numbers. You're best off switching to a different scripting language.

Comment: Is there a command to replace `seq` that can generate that list so I can use it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I also tried $ for i in $(seq 3.0 4.5 0.1); do echo $i; done but nothing happens.

The order is wrong:

```
$ for i in $(seq 3.0 0.1 4.5); do echo $i; done
```

Comment: Wow, thanks this works great. Much easier to read than the other methods.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a loop from 3.5 to 4.5 in 0.1 steps this would work

```
for x in {35..45}; do
     y=`bc <<< "scale=1; $x/10"`
     echo $y
done
```

The same with 0.01 steps

```
for x in {350..450}; do
         y=`bc <<< "scale=2; $x/100"`
         echo $y
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is `bc` compulsory for the division?

Comment: Just googled it, now I'm using `for x in {30..45}; do y=$(dc <<< "1k $x 10/p"); echo $y; done`.

Comment: Yeah, either one works. bash only support integer arithmetic. Therefore, one always needs to use another program...

Answer (score -2):

```
 for i in {3.0,4.5,0.1}; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: No, that only prints three lines 3.0, 4.5 and 0.1.

Comment: What do you want to print ??

Comment: A range of decimal numbers, e.g. `3.0 3.1 3.2 3.3 ... 4.5`

Comment: @izxle - The original question was prone to misunderstandings. The syntax shown here is useful for what it was meant to.

Comment: What this syntax is "meant to do", however, has no reasonable relationship with "loop[ing] through a range of decimal numbers".